# Java loop not running

Tags: java

Why would this function:

```
    public static int test(int[] a, int v)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == v)
                return I;
            else return -1;
        }
    }
```

not compile given `a` = {0,2,3,4} and `v` = 2?

It seems like the loop should run and return *-1* since the first element isn't `v`.

Comment: It doesn't compile because not all paths return a value. Nothing is returned if the `for` loop is never entered

Comment: Aside from main question do you realize your loop can iterate only *once* because in each branch of `if` you are returning a value (which stops execution of method, including execution of loop)?

Answer (score 2):

The method must return an `int` because it has been declared to do so.

The compiler can't know that the `for` loop will actually run because input a might be length 0.  So it throws an error because if length is 0 the `for` loop will never run.

Put a return statement after the `for` loop (outside it).

Answer (score 2):

You should have a return statement for the case if For loop will not iterate even once. e.g. if you pass an empty array.
It isn't the best way to implement your logic, but for your implementation, you need to add a return after for loop like this.

Also you probably want to remove *else* branch since this would cause returning -1 if first element of array is not equal to searched element `v` which will stop execution of `test` method entirely.

```
public static int test(int[] a, int v) {
  for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i] == v) {
      return i;
    } 
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Comment: I think you mean ""will iterate *not* even once".

Comment: @Alan True, fixed (hopefully).

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the return statement of the method. Try this:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println(MyClass.test(new int[]{0,2,3,4}, 2));
    }
    
    public static int test(int[] a, int v) {
        int result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] == v)
                result = i;
            else
                result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

[Live demo](https://www.jdoodle.com/ia/f1p)

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution would be to strip out the loop, as `return` is called in the first iteration, even if `a[i] == v` is false. So the method should look like this:

```
public static int test(int[] a, int v)
{
 if (a[0] == v)
   return a[0];
 else return -1;
}
```

Comment: There still is `i` returned. It should probably `return 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

the first element isn't V so the program will default to the else statement where you return -1, in essence, the return statement cancels the termination hence the loop will only execute once

```
public static int test(int[] a, int v)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[i] == v)
            return i;
    }
     return -1;
}
```

A more viable option is to use the return -1 condition outside the loop which will be executed once all the elements of the array do not match v